# Pymodm + Flask connection issues

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymodm

I'm trying to use the pymodm (mongo orm) library in a flask app.

I have this line in my **init**.py file:

```
connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test')
```

where I also call

```
from views import main
```

My main.py views file has this simple view:

```
@app.route('/get_objects/', methods=['GET'])
def get_objects_url():

    test_objects = models.TestObjects.objects.raw({})
```

Now test objects should contain 5 documents, however it instead contains 0.  I can see the connection from both the MongoDB side and the Flask side, however no data is being retrieved from MongoDB.

Oddly, running all of this code without Flask results in a successful retrieval of the data. Odder still, I can SAVE objects I just can't retrieve them.

Has anyone had any experience with Pymodm and Flask? is there a better alternative?

Comment: Flask MongoEngine?

Comment: Determined the issue was the _cls value.  Apparently it had changed due to the new import path, from model.TestObjects to app.model.TestObjects.

Comment: Then perhaps you can write an answer to your question to help others who might stumble on the same issue